# Trying to create an expandable menu with only html and css

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm pretty new to coding in general and have been learning CSS. I'm trying to create a drop-down menu page for a website and I'm having difficulty; I understand that JavaScript could probably help with this, but I don't have the time to learn a whole new language.

I've written this code to expand a ul to be visible when a checkbox is checked:

```css
#nav-bar ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  visibility: hidden
}

#menu:checked~#nav-bar ul {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 25vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-nav-container" id="nav-bar" style="display: block">
  <div class="snc-header">
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu">
  </div>
  <nav class="site-nav">
    <ul id="menu-primary-nav" class="sn-level-1">
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item3</li>
      <li>item4</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Your input (#menu) is not a sibling of the ul and so cannot influence it using CSS. You'll need to restructure your HTML.

Comment: What difficulty in particular are you having? And what have you tried? What is your expected result/behaviour and what are you actually observing?

Comment: Ideally, once you check the checkbox, the ul should appear on the right side of the screen as a menu bar taking up the full height and quarter width of the screen and disappear once you uncheck the checkbox. Right now, the checkbox is showing but nothing happens when you check it. I've placed it inside the nav tag and ul tag but nothing has changed.

Comment: You would have to move the `nav` tag, not the checkbox; move it into the same containing element (i.e. `.snc-header`) as the checkbox, and place it _after_ the checkbox so that the general sibling combinator (`~`) is still valid.
You'll also want to update your style rule selector to use the `nav` class, or add the missing id attribute to the `nav` element - your css rules are targeting elements with ids that don't exist.

Comment: It worked! thanks so much!